# interpreter suddenly stops on creating mulitple threads in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I' trying to fill by database with information, which is being downloaded from the internet, on the fly. I already have a list of `id`s in a table. What I initially tried is to get all the `id`s and traverse each `id` in a loop and download the relevant information. It worked, but, since I had more than 1000 `id`s it took approximately 24 hours. To speed up I tried to create threads, with each thread allotted some number of `id`s to download. THE problem here is that interpreter suddenly stops and exits. **I also want to ask if the procedure what I wrote will actually gain me some speedup in overall time ?** The code I wrote is something like this(I'm using `ruby`):

```
def self.called_by_thread(start, limit=50, retry_attempts = 5)
last_id = start
begin
  @Users = User.where('id > ' + last_id.to_s).limit(limit)
  @Users.each do |user|
    #called a function to download information of user and store it,
    #This function belongs to the user object
    last_id = user.id
  end
rescue => msg
  puts "Something went wrong (" + msg + ")"
  if retry_attempts > 0
    retry_attempts -= 1
    limit -= last_id-start
    retry
  end
end

end
```

In the above code `start` is the `id` from where to start.
I call the above function like this:

```
last_id = 1090
i = 1
limit = 50
workers = []
while i < num_workers
  t = Thread.new { called_by_thread(last_id, limit, 5) }
  workers << t
  i += 1
  last_id += limit
end
workers.each do |t|
  t.join
end
```

all `id`s are incremental, so their is no harm in adding a positive number to it. It is guaranteed that the user exists for a given `id`. Provided its below 10000.